# how to use asp server control in mvc 2,like text box,button,check list box grid view?

Tags: c#

I just want to do the add, update delete search function using asp.net server control in MVC 2.

But I cannot do that. And I also want to use the grid in MVC 2.

I use this..

```
    HtmlInputCheckBox chk = new HtmlInputCheckBox();
    ArrayList list = GetAllControls(new ArrayList(), chk.GetType(), this);

    foreach (Control c in list)
    {
        if (c is HtmlInputCheckBox)
        {
            string name = ((HtmlInputCheckBox)c).ID;
            bool check = ((HtmlInputCheckBox)c).Checked;
            string value = ((HtmlInputCheckBox)c).Value;
            this.Label1.Text += "Name: " + name + "\nStatus: " + check.ToString() + "\nValue: " + value;
        }

    }

}      
public static ArrayList GetAllControls(ArrayList list, Type type, Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (c.GetType() == type)
        {
            list.Add(c);

        }
        if (c.HasControls())
        {
            list = GetAllControls(list, type, c);
        }

    }

    return list;
}
```

But its not work properly....... I just want to use here the server control instead of the html controls...

Comment: I don't think it's possible. In Asp MVC you don't have the page lifecicle like in ASP.Net. I don't think you can use ASP.Net Controls in MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET Server controls are for Web Forms, not MVC. There's no link between the View & the Controller other that the Model.

In the controller you can **never** try to access the controls rendered in the view in the same manner as you can in Web Forms, the simple reason for it being that the view hasn't been rendered yet. Also, like @Dannydust commented, MVC applications doesn't have any viewstate and therefor no lifecycle that maintains controls rendered on a previous page view.

You'll have to accept the flow of the MVC application which is

1. Request comes in
2. The routing determines what to do
3. A Controller / Action gets invoked (hopefully)

   1. Controller builds a model
   2. Controller passes on the model to view
4. View gets invoked and renders the model

Once you've hit number **4** there's no going back to the controller and try to execute server logic. If I were to guess what you're trying to achieve it would be something like this in MVC:

**The model**

```
public class MyModel {
  public bool Value1 { get; set; }
  public bool Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

**The controller**

```
public class MyController : Controller {
  public ActionResult Index() {
    return View(new MyModel());
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Save(MyModel model) {
    // The values of the model will now be updated from the view
  }
}
```

**The view**

```
@model MyModel

<h2>Welcome to the view</h2>
@{ Html.BeginForm("Save"); }
<ul>
  <li>Value1: @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Value1)</li>
  <li>Value2: @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Value2)</li>
</ul>
<button type="submit">Save it</button>
@{ Html.EndForm(); }
```

The above code is not tested in any way, but I'm hoping you get the idea of how it works :)

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to access the controls available in the view in your controller. If my understanding is correct, then I would say this should not be the proper way to work with MVC. 
In MVC you can strongly type your views with your Model(or UxModel), which is nothing but a POCO class and on form POST you can retrieve the values keyed into the properties -by end user- in your action method. After that you can do all the manipulation on your model in your controller.

If you try to access the controls of view in your controller then that is a clear violation of concept 'separation of concern'.

Answer (score 0):

better you can use HtmlGenericControl

HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");